# Spree on Dreamhost via FastCGI = TypeError (can't dup NilClass)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, dreamhost, spree

I am playing around with Spree on my shared Dreamhost account. To install it I had to run the domain under FastCGI and upgrade my rubygems manually.

After all of that and setting up FastCGI I created a dummy site, a blank index controller and gt it up and running.

I then installed spree and now my app fails to load and all I get in my production logs is:

> Started GET "/" for 68.147.237.245 at Wed Feb 22 22:22:59 -0800 2012
>
> TypeError (can't dup NilClass):

If I switch my routes back to my original config and restart the fcgi script it runs fine but back to Spree and it fails again.

Any ideas here?  Not even sure where to start.  The usual Google searches do not come up with anything else like this.

Comment: Just an update... the answer ended up being Heroku :^)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an update... the answer ended up being Heroku :^)